# How to separate controller from model when already mixed?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I'm not sure if this is exactly a MVC pattern, but what I'm trying to do is separate all the data layer (which in a few words is all that would be serialized to an XML file), from its actions. Implementing MVC just for the sake of it is really not my aim here. So if this is not exactly MVC, I'm fine with that.

Say, for instance, I have this classes (these are just sample classes that try to illustrate my problem, not my actual classes):

```
public class MixedSubClass
{
    public string SomeData {get;set;}

    public void DoSomeActionWhichRequiresControls(Control someControl)
    {
        // do stuff            
    }
}

public class MixedClass
{
    private Control _SomeControl;

    public List<MixedSubClass> _SubClasses = new List<MixedSubClass>();
    public List<MixedSubClass> SubClasses { get { return _SubClasses; } }

    public MixedClass(Control someControl)
    {
        _SomeControl = someControl;
    }

    public void DoSomeMoreActionsWhichRequiresControls()
    {
        foreach (var subClass in SubClasses)
        {
            subClass.DoSomeActionWhichRequiresControls(_SomeControl);
        }
        // Do more stuff
    }
}
```

So when I serialize `MixedClass`, only public fields get serialized, which is what I want. But now I want to have an only data layer, which doesn't even require the `Windows.Forms` assembly. I want to stay with this:

```
public class MixedSubClass
{
    public string SomeData {get;set;}
}

public class MixedClass
{
    public List<MixedSubClass> _SubClasses = new List<MixedSubClass>();
    public List<MixedSubClass> SubClasses { get { return _SubClasses; } }
}
```

And put all this into an independent assembly. But my problem now is how to turn this back to the previous thing. First thing I thought was using extension methods, but, as you can see in my sample code, sometimes I need to store some value that is not serializable, such as the `Control _SomeControl`. Also, on real life, these lists are lists of lists, trees and more complicated stuff like that so I need a some good foundation before I get started (actually I already have a project with all my data layer by itself which compiles fine without `Windows.Forms`, but now I'm having trouble putting it back together).

How would you handle this? Should I just not separate the data layer this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing fine so far.  Your data layer should absolutley be free of references to UI controls (whether they be winform, web, etc).

While it is hard to give an exact code sample based on what you've posted, you need to add a set of controller-like classes that map your data (aka model) onto your user-interface (aka view).  They should hold a reference to both the data and UI objects and be the ones to perform th work that you stripped out (`DoSomeActionWhichRequiresControls`).